# fill an array with differents randoms integers Python

Tags: python, arrays, random

I need to fill an array with a randoms numbers in such a manner as the numbers will not be repeated .

The numbers are an integers values  which varying from 0 to 9, and the array length is 4.

`target = [random.randint(0,9) for i in range(4)]`.  What should i add as condition to prevent the numbers repetition ?

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

What you need is shuffling: first you create an array of length 10 with the numbers from 0 to 9, then you [shuffle](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)  it, then you return the first 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.sample`. This returns n unique random values from a given list.

```
import random
target = random.sample(range(0,9),4)  # get 4 values from 0-8
```

For clarity, `sample` returns values from unique *positions* within the list. It does not guarantee the actual values will be unique.

```
random.sample([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],4) # returns [1,2.2.1]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help , as you said @Mike67 , it's working with random.sample

Answer (score 0):

You can use python random.sample(sequence, k).
It chooses 'k' unique elements from a population sequence or set.
For example,
`import random target = random.sample(range(0,9), 4)` 
Hope it to be helpful for you.